# When ought a question be deleted?

Tags: discussion, deleting

I recently asked the question [Problem with Compiling .pdf](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/159121/problem-with-compiling-pdf). Clearly, it has been put on hold, and reasonably so given the close reason at the time it was closed. Now, there is a new answer that renders the reason it was closed a bit inaccurate. As the OP, should I delete the question? Or should the question be reopened?

Answer (score 7):

I would think the community's voting behaviour should speak for itself in judging which of the two answers are valid/useful. Additionally, if you feel that the second answer is "[not useful](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Cjyr.png)", vote accordingly.

Finally, consider the community. Does the post in its current form serve a broader audience? If at all, it's worth keeping.

Comment: Note: Second Answer is a self answer by OP/Meta Q OP as well. So he may not vote for his own post

Comment: @texenthusiast: Good point...